# Scope and Relation doesn't work together - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model, scope

**User Model**

```
    class User extends Authenticatable
    {
        use HasApiTokens,HasFactory, Notifiable;
        
        protected $table = "users";
        protected $primaryKey = 'ID';
    
        public function scopeActive($query)
        {
            return $query->where('activated', 1);
        }

        public function followings()
        {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Contacts','user_id','ID')->active();
        }
```

**Contacts Model**

```
class Contacts extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "contacts";
    protected $primaryKey = 'ID';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'ID');
    }
```

When I call **User::find(1)->followings()->count()** on Tinker I get

```
BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::active()'
```

How can I get followings whose activated = 1 only?

Comment: What is the code for the Contacts Model

Comment: scopeActive() work for only user model not for contacts. if you want write another scopeActive in Contacts model.

Comment: @the_hasanov should I write the same scopeActive in Contacts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding a custom scope to Contacts model

```
public function scopeActiveFollowings($query)
    {
        return $query->join('users', function($join)
            {
                $join->on('users.ID', '=', 'contacts.contact_id')
                    ->where('activated', '=', 1);
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel model has a property called  [query](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_query).

This property is used automatically when you call a query for the model
these two statements are exactly the same:

```
User::query()->where('id',1)->get();
User::where('id',1)->get();
```

When you call query() directly or indirectly, Laravel register the scopes in this [line](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/a6680d98f9dadaa363aa7d5218517a08706cee64/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1172)

when you use  `$this->hasMany('App\Models\Contacts','user_id','ID')` the result will be from class [HasMany](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasMany.php) and this class doesn't have a method called active(), this is why you see this error.

to fix it, you have to apply the scope when you use User model query:

```
$result=User::query()->activated()->with('followings')->findOrFail(1);
```

if you want the followings count for the activated user using scope, you should apply this scope on Following Model:

```
public function scopeHasActivedUser($query)
{
    return $query->whereHas('user', function($query)
              {
                 $query->where('users.activated', 1);
              });
        }
```

In the controller:

```
$fllowingsCountForActivatedUser=Fllowing::query()->hasActivedUser()->count();
```

If I were you, I would get the result this way:

```
$user=User::withCount(['followings'=>function($query){
$query->where('users.activated', 1)})])->find(1);
```

now the $user model instance should have a property called 'followings_count' for the only activated followings count

Comment: Tried with User::query()->active()->with('followings')->findOrFail(1)->count(); but didn't work

Comment: you can not use count after findOrFail, findOrFail will get only 1 record or fill

Comment: you want flowings count?

Comment: I want followings count with activated = 1

Comment: But how can I specify the user id, I mean I need to get a users followings (example user id 1)